# Multiple mono_jit_init/mono_jit_cleanup issue

Tags: .net, mono, garbage-collection, jit

I am working on some application in which I am required to call mono_jit_init multiple times. When I run my application for the first time I do mono_jit_init then mono_jit_cleanup everything works fine, problem occurs when I try do mono_jit_init again(this time to load different runtime[this is my requirement :(]). And on the mono website it is mentioned that we should init mono runtime once in a process. I have searched for this issue and didnt find any working solution. So, I want to know is there anything possible that can be done for this issue? And also if possible can anybody elaborate why mono_jit_init multiple times is not supported? Is it related to some GC cleanup issue?

Answer (score 1):

Looking at the Mono source code the crash seems to be related to the way the Mono runtime is initialized (relying on zeroed variables).

So you have to call `mono_jit_init()` once in the life of the runtime.

That means your application's life if the library is statically loaded but only a load/unload cycle if the Mono runtime is loaded dynamically via `dl_open()`. Besides the extra work of caching Mono function pointers, this workaround may not be practical to run concurrent Mono tasks.

Another way to proceed (and which supports concurrent runs) is to cache the runtime context for further uses instead of creating it repeatedly with `mono_jit_init()`. You will have to use a dedicated Mono `domain` to do fancy things like unloading `assemblies`.

There's always a solution. It just takes time to find one that works best for your needs.